# What is this tall potted plant with narrow leaves and braided bark at the base?

Tags: identification, trees, houseplants, indoors

We recently inherited a new plant with no information about the species or location where it naturally grows.  It looks like it has been regularly trimmed by the previous owner, and I'm not sure if the braided trunk at the bottom is naturally occurring or if that was shaped by the owner.  Also, it has a height of about 1.4 meters (55 inches).  On average, there are about 6 leaflets per leaf.

Any ideas on what this plant species is?  Or any general ideas about the family or order?

Also, I'm living in the Netherlands.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site James!  That's an interesting looking plant. Thanks for all of the details and pictures. Since location's often important with identification questions, would you please add where you live? Thanks!

Comment: Location added!

Comment: I have the same question! Came across three of these trees, about 6' tall, planted in front of the local library. My friend says they're bottle trees, but it does not seem quite right, because the leaves on this mystery tree do not merge at their base, they remain separate. The braiding of the trunk does seem to suggest money tree, but the leaves are too thin for that. If you ever learned more about what tree you have, would love to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Brachychiton rupestris, commonly known as the narrow-leaved bottle tree or Queensland bottle tree, is a tree in the family Malvaceae native to Queensland, Australia. ~Wikipedia

[image]

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachychiton_rupestris

As a houseplant (bonsai): http://www.indoor-plant-care.com/plant-list/brachychiton-rupestris/

Identification Photos: https://www.google.ca/search?q=brachychiton+rupestris+houseplant&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=921&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia6J6A0b7MAhWHmIMKHcU-D24QsAQIGg

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that's a variation of an pachira aquatica.

Comment: Can you add more details so the user can find out how to care for the plant?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response!  _Pachira aquatica_ definitely looks like its on the right track, but I had trouble finding and pictures of it or related species which also has leaves as thin as ours.  I'm holding off on accepting this as an answer for a few more days, but if no closer matches appear or if I come across a picture of this species with thin leaves, I'll take this as the answer!